# Resizing img when hovering makes other images move

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have 4 pictures in a line as links and I made them resize when hovering, but when I hover one of the pictures it resize as I expect it to do but the other un-hovered images moves down with 50px. 
How do I avoid the other pictures moving down?

My code is:
HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="cover (1).jpg" class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (2).jpg"class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (3).jpg"class="cover"><a>
<a href=""><img src="cover (4).jpg"class="cover"><a>
```

Css:

```
img.cover{
height:100px;
Width:100px;
padding-top:25px;}

img.cover:hover {
height:150px; 
width:150px;
margin-top:auto;}
```

Comment: What do you want the other pictures to do when hovering over an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want the other pictures to remain in the same position, you're looking for [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme).

Or if you only want all four of them to align to the top instead of the bottom, replace the`margin-top:auto` with `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: The vertical-align:top Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, can I ask where your name comes from? It sounds rather... international.

Comment: I'm part Thai, part Greenlandic, and Danish :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Expanded the answer [with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/G5ty4/6/) to show all that is necessary for the absolute positioning, since Mr Lister did not like my shorter version pointing simply to the fact that absolute positioning was needed to take them out of flow:

HTML

```
<a href="" class="cover"><img src="cover (1).jpg" /></a>
<a href="" class="cover"><img src="cover (2).jpg" /></a>
<a href="" class="cover"><img src="cover (3).jpg" /></a>
<a href="" class="cover"><img src="cover (4).jpg" /></a>
```

CSS

```
.cover {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;    
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding-top:25px;    
}

.cover img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.cover img:hover {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that? That doesn't work by itself. Only giving the images an absolute position means there is no more space reserved inside the `a`s for them, and the `a`s will collapse to a zero width.

Comment: @MrLister--expanded the information. BTW, +1 for your `vertical-align` answer. Nice.

Comment: @MrLister--that's okay, I probably deserved the down vote for not being clearer what needed to be done to use absolute positioning to solve the issue. Now if you want to pull my new answer out of the negative... :-)